# Problem with natbib and agsm style not showing Vol No and Pp in references

Tags: bibtex, natbib, harvard-style

I am using natbib with the agsm style,

if i have an entry as;

```
@article{Buchko2007,
author = {Buchko, Aaron A.},
title= {The effect of leadership on values-based management},
year = {2007},
journal = {Leadership \& Organization Development Journal},
volume = {28},
number = {1},
pages = {36-50},
doi = {10.1108/01437730710718236}
}
```

I get the following;

> Buchko, A. A. (2007), `The effect of leadership on values-based management', *Leadership & Organization Development Journal* **28**(1), 36-50.

But I believe I can get the following;

> Buchko, A. A. (2007), `The effect of leadership on values-based management', *Leadership & Organization Development Journal* **Vol. 28 No. 1 pp. 36-50**.

What am I doing wrong?

a minimum working example would be as follows;

```
\documentclass [a4paper,notitlepage,11pt] {article}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\title{title}
\author{author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

% content
\citet[p.~38]{ Buchko2007} states organisation values as a ``specific set of ... sta

\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{bib}{}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think you're doing anything wrong. I get exactly the same output as you report when I run LaTeX and BibTeX on an MWE (minimum working example) that takes your entry and specifies `agsm` as the bibliography style. (You *are* loading the both the `natbib` and `har2nat` packages, to make the `agsm` bibliography style work with `natbib`, right?)

Comment: @Mico, I somewhat agree, but if you look at agsm.bst
you have lines that clearly show there is code to show the second option, ie line 349 `{ "pp.~" pages n.dashify * }`, line 356 `FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}` and line 282 `{ "Vol." volume tie.or.space.connect`

Comment: @Mico, i don't load har2nat as I believe that only affects the way you cite the references, not the display of references. either-way I get the same results anyway.

Comment: from a bit of investigating, it looks like the Vol and PP only come up with types inproceedings or incollection. And there is no allowance for "No.".

Comment: i guess the question should now be, which style will give me what I am after?

Comment: I think `biblatex` will support your request.

Answer (score 3):

The function `article` of your style uses another output routine as other functions. To achieve what you want you have to change two functions as shown below. However I really recommend `biblatex` which is more suitable to customize the bibliography.

**First Function `format.vol.num.pages`**:

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume embolden field.or.null
  number empty$
    'skip$
    { "{\ \bf No.\ " number * "}" * *
      volume empty$
    { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
    'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  pages empty$
    'skip$
    { duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ format.pages }
    { ",~pp.~" * pages n.dashify * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

**Second Function `embolden`**

```
FUNCTION {embolden}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "{\bf Vol.\ " swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
```

After this changes you get:

> [image]