# Use of the right bibliography style to obtain particular format for paper cite

Tags: bibliographies, ieee-style

I already try to find a solution without asking any question but I didn't find anything.

I'm working in a document with the following specific:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage{ae} 
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{alltt}
and others...
```

and at the end of my document I have the bibliography with the following command:

```
\nocite{}
    \newpage
    \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
    \bibliography{bibliografia}
```

Citing a paper I obtain the following result: 
[image: example of the result]

Instead of 52(2):90-96 I would like to have vol. 52 and pp.90-96.

Any idea to obtain this format with my specific? Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The simplest wa to customise is to use `biblatex`.

Comment: @Bernard Am I already using biblatex? How should I use it?

Comment: I guess not, since you use the usual syntax, and biblatex changes it slightly. I'm preparing a code. Btw, you do not want the `number` of the volume to appear?

Comment: @Bernard, thanks for your help. Instead of 52(2):90-96 I would prefer vol. 52 n.2 pp. 90-96.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way, starting from `biblatex-ieee` which seems to be closest to what you want. I only had to modify a few macros, with the help of the `xpatch` package. Note that I had to change the default ‘unit punctuation’ (default punctuation between groups of elements in a bibliographic entry) from a comma back to a fullstop (default in generic biblatex), but this might have side effects on ther types of entries.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{btas,
author = {B. Bangerter and S. Talwar and R. Arefi and K. Stewart},
title = {Networks and devices for the 5g era},
journal= {IEEE Communications Magazine},
volume = {52},
number = {2},
pages = {90--96},
year = {2014},
month = {2},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=ieee, sorting=none, ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}

\renewcommand\newunitpunct{\adddot\space}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
\usebibmacro{journal}%
\setunit{\addcomma\space}
\iffieldundef{series}
{}
{%
\newunit
\printfield{series}%
\setunit{\addcomma\space}
}%
\usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
\setunit{\addspace}%
}%

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibdriver{article}{%
\newunit
\usebibmacro{issue+date}%
}%
{%
\setunit{\addcomma\space}
\usebibmacro{issue+date}%
}{}{}

\xpatchbibmacro{volume+number+eid}{%
\addspace
\printfield{volume}%
\newunit}%
{%
\addspace
\printfield{volume}%
\setunit{\addspace}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[type=article]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help Bernard. I try to use this, but is quite difficult for me to understand each step. Anyway I have problems in the use of package biblatex, I don't know why but I think is for the template I'm using (in the document class I'm using a book and not an article). 
Also in here (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103561/problem-with-natbib-and-agsm-style-not-showing-vol-no-and-pp-in-references) there is a solution that I would like to use but I don't know where to write those functions.

Comment: I thought that only a particular bibliographystyle were necessary!

Comment: If you want a formatting that is not quite covered by one of the existing styles, you have to start from the closest, and patch it. It's easier with biblatex than using a traditional bib style…